# Android C2DM: Problems to receive message in device

Tags: php, android-manifest, android-c2dm

I'm facing a problem when i try to receive message in my device, everything works fine but when i try to reiceve it nothing come, i'm getting:

id=0:1319039498507602%b50b7d2400000031

from https://android.apis.google.com/c2dm/send

it mean that message sent, isn't?

but i can't receive it in device.

someone could help me?

thanks in advance.

**Edit: My manifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="clouders.com" android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />

    <permission
        android:name="clouders.com.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />
    <uses-permission
        android:name="clouders.com.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />

    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
        <activity android:name=".C2DMClientActivity" android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <receiver android:name=".C2DMRegistrationReceiver"
            android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION"></action>
                <category android:name="clouders.com" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <receiver android:name=".C2DMMessageReceiver"
            android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE"></action>
                <category android:name="clouders.com" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <activity android:name="RegistrationResultActivity"></activity>
        <activity android:name="MessageReceivedActivity"></activity>

    </application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: If you aren't receiving it on the device then everything isn't working fine. Post your AndroidManifest entries for your C2DM receiver and the permissions you are requesting.

Answer (score 1):

based on the lists of possible response codes: http://code.google.com/android/c2dm/#server, I believe you registered the server sending the message appropriately with google c2dm service, and you have used the correct authentication key for the server and registration id for the android phone, **so google c2dm got the message and sent you back a response code 200 along with id=0:1319039498507602%b50b7d2400000031 as the http response content where 0:1319039498507602%b50b7d2400000031 is the ID of the sent message**. I don't know if you found a solution yet but I would suggest the following troubleshooting/debug mechanism in order since it might help someone else:

1) What is the message/payload parameter in your https request to the c2dm server because you will need this for debugging on the phone

2) Make sure you have a google account signed in on the phone e.g.gmail. You can do this under the phone Settings > Accounts & Sync...

3) Make sure the device/phone is registered and the server is using the registration id currently on the phone. You can check this but logging the response from your registration. Actually, the server should be able to reach the phone via c2dm even if the registration id on the phone has changed but just to be triple sure, lol, use the same at both ends. Also in the intent you use to register your android device, use the email the server used for registration with c2dm as the sender parameter.

4) Log the incoming messages from c2dm. I see you have a C2DMMessageReceiver class. You can do it in there. With that you can see the payload parameter from the server. You can also create a notification when the message arrives with the payload as the content. You can also use a Toast on android for quick display.

I hope all these help.

Answer (score 0):

How have you set up your third party server (C2DM-sharp or PHP based)? I would verify the client code by comparing with one of the examples like google chrome-to-phone. Also make sure your registered C2DM email address and password are correct.

Comment: i'm using php to get auth token and then send message.

Comment: Are you getting a response back from the cloud?

Comment: i'm getting id=0:1319039498507602%b50b7d2400000031 from https://android.apis.google.com/c2dm/send

Comment: Have you verified that your client is sending it's C2DM registration ID to your web service? You'll need a valid registration ID, as well as the proper credentials and application name to send a successful payload to the cloud.

Comment: yes i have a valid registration id cuz when i try to put a invalid registration id i get Errors but when i put this valid registration id i get: id=0:1319039498507602%b50b7d2400000031, i guess it worked, isn't?

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked if it could be an encoding problem? Your ids seem to be encoded (I mean this %b50 ?).

The id you get from https://android.apis.google.com/c2dm/send is a message id. 
In the comments you posted the same ID as your registration id? 
This should not be the same.